# Thread aborts in a dynamic library before it has finished executing code

Tags: c++, visual-studio, c++11, dll, std

I'm working on a library which will be C API compatible.

Within the library there will be a global instance of an object which will have a `std::thread` as a member. It seems that of some reason when the `main` returns and `exit()` is called, thread is automatically killed/terminated. This doesn't happen if the code is used within the same project (directly in the executable and not through a library).

I expect the following example to run in an infinite loop: `while(1) {...}` and `thread.join()` should block each other. It doesn't when it's with a library, the thread seems to have been already killed/finished when the destructor of `CThread` is called. What am I missing here?

**CThread.h**

```
#ifndef CTHREAD_H
#define CTHREAD_H

#ifdef EXPORT_C_THREAD
# define EXPORT_CTHREAD __declspec(dllexport) __cdecl
#else
# define EXPORT_CTHREAD __declspec(dllimport) __cdecl
#endif

void EXPORT_CTHREAD testFunc();

#endif
```

**CThread.cpp**

```
#include "CThread.h"

#include <thread>
#include <memory>

class CThread
{
   std::thread m_thread;
   void infiniteLoop()
   {
      while (1) {
         std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::microseconds(100));
      }
   }
public:
   CThread()
   {
      m_thread = std::thread(&CThread::infiniteLoop, this);
   }

   ~CThread()
   {
      m_thread.join();
   }

};

std::unique_ptr<CThread> cthread;

void testFunc()
{
   cthread = std::make_unique<CThread>();
}
```

**main.cpp** (this is in another project. I'm linking to the library above.)

```
#include "CThread.h"

int main()
{
   testFunc();
    return 0;
}
```

**Update**

As suggested I've tried to initialize the `cthread`-object in the `DllMain()`-function's during `DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH` and deallocate during `DLL_PROCESS_DETACH`. Since the `DllMain()`-function will acquire the loader lock I have to initialize the thread later. However, as before, the thread is already aborted when `DLL_PROCESS_DETACH` is "called". `DLL_THREAD_DETACH` won't get called on exit.

Any more suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: this is not `C` code so please remove the `c` tag.

Comment: Since it's a C interface for the library I thought it was OK. It's removed now.

Comment: Visual Studio 2013

Comment: DLL calls don't export C++ semantics.  Look at [DllMain](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682583%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) with *fdwReason = DLL_PROCESS_DETACH* for DLL cleanup.

Comment: @RyanBemrose I'm not exporting any C++ semantics (just a C-function).  The DLL is not detached before the thread is aborted. The global instance cthread is still available when the thread is aborted. Can you please give me some additional information/comments what you mean regarding the DLL cleanup? Thanks!

Comment: @A.Fagrell Destructors are C++ semantics.  Destructors are not guaranteed to get called across a DLL boundary.  This includes almost all RAII semantics such as `unique_ptr`  The only completely safe way to cross a DLL boundary is to treat it like C code.  No objects returned or passed in as parameters (only POD).  No exceptions thrown across the boundary. etc.  Often you can get away with it by building the exe and dll together, but Windows makes no guarantees.

Comment: @RyanBemrose across the interface there is no C++ semantics. I'm not returning or passing in any C++ objects? I'm not sure how your comment helps me? What's the solution? Only use C in the whole library?

Comment: It means that when the main process exits, there is no guarantee that object destructors in your DLL will be called.  If you want code to run reliably at process exit, you should do it in `DllMain()`.  That also means don't use global static objects in the DLL that need destruction.  If you need something to act like a global, create them during DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH and delete them during DLL_PROCESS_DETACH.

Comment: Thanks @RyanBemrose I will try your solution. Where can I find information about this? I mean about why the the object destructors in the DLL is not guranteed to get called?

Comment: @RyanBemrose didn't work, when DLL_PROCESS_DETACH is "called" the thread is already terminated. The DLL_THREAD_DETACH is not "called" since the dll will unload on exit().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am able to reproduce this behaviour with VS2015.

The issue is with the `std::unique_ptr<CThread> pthread;` being a global object. The deletion of the pointer is not tied to the execution of the `main` thread. The global data of the dll and the global data of the host exe do not synchronise with each other in a predictable manner. There are further complications when introducing threads, these are stopped as the process exits.

As you have noted, moving all the code to a single exe allows for the global data to synchronise appropriately on the `main` thread.

To work around this, you can either export an RAII styled class to manage the thread's execution or simply provide a "clear thread" or cleanup function and export that as well; the function would then have the following form;

```
void cleanupData()
{
   cthread = nullptr; // block waiting for thread exit
}
```

To further assist client code, an RAII class can still be provided that supports this "clear thread", but it need not be exported from the dll.

The client side RAII could piggy back off of `std::unique_ptr` or `std::shared_ptr` as required. The simplest form would look like;

```
struct Cleanup {
    Cleanup() = default;
    Cleanup(Cleanup const&) = delete;
    Cleanup& operator=(Cleanup const&) = delete;
    Cleanup(Cleanup&&) = delete;
    Cleanup& operator=(Cleanup&&) = delete;

    ~Cleanup() { cleanupData(); } // clean up the threads...
};
```

And this is required to be tied to the lifetime of the data begin used or imported from the dll.

And used as;

```
{
    auto cleanup = std::make_unique<Cleanup>();
    testFunc();
    // ...
}
```

*As an aside*
In the destructor, before you `join()` the thread, test to make sure it is `joinable()`.

---

Given the update; can this be changed or improved, i.e. can the thread be controlled once the execution leaves `main`? TL;DR, no.

Raymond Chen of "the old new thing" fame, quotes from [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20100827-00/?p=13023):

> On the other hand, the C runtime library automatically calls `ExitProcess` when you exit the `main` thread, regardless of whether there are any worker threads still active. This behavior for console programs is mandated by the C language, which says that (5.1.2.2.3) “a return from the initial call to the `main` function is equivalent to calling the exit function with the value returned by the `main` function as its argument.” The C++ language has an equivalent requirement (3.6.1). Presumably, the C runtime folks carried this behavior to `WinMain` for consistency.

What does [`ExitProcess()` do](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682658(v=vs.85).aspx)?

> ...
>
> 1. All of the threads in the process, except the calling thread, terminate their execution without receiving a `DLL_THREAD_DETACH` notification.
> 2. The states of all of the threads terminated in step 1 become signaled.
> 3. The entry-point functions of all loaded dynamic-link libraries (DLLs) are called with `DLL_PROCESS_DETACH`.
>
> ...

In particular, points 1 and 3 above, by the time the destructor of `std::unique_ptr<CThread>` runs, the thread is already stopped and signalled. You cannot rely on background thread execution once the main thread has called `ExitProcess()`, they have already been stopped and the OS is in the process of cleaning up all the resources associated with the process.

---

You mention in the comments;

> I will use an IPC mutex within the thread so it's critical that is cleaned up properly.

If the issue is a mutex and not just a thread, that changes the problem quiet a bit. It is easier then to extract the mutex to a global level and allow `DllMain` to (with `DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH` etc.) to manage it. The thread would be allowed access thereof as per normal. There may be some additional code to signal the state of the mutex, but that can all be managed with the dll as well.

Bear in mind as well that IPC mutex mechanisms usually include an "abandoned" state for this exact purpose. If the holder of the mutex fails unexpectedly and abandons the mutex, the remaining clients of the mutex are notified of this when the try access the mutex.

From the [WIN32 Mutex](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684266(v=vs.85).aspx):

> If a thread terminates without releasing its ownership of a mutex object, the mutex object is considered to be abandoned. A waiting thread can acquire ownership of an abandoned mutex object, but the wait function will return `WAIT_ABANDONED` to indicate that the mutex object is abandoned...

Comment: Thanks for the help and verifying that the same issue is possible to reproduce on VS2015. The code I've shown here is just a small part of the library, just used to illustrate the problem. In the "real" code I have an Open() and a Close()-function to clean up resources. However, I hoped that I could automatically clean up the resources without forcing the client to make sure they've called the Close()-function (if they forget or if the program would crash). Could you give me some guidelines on how such an RAII styled class would look like? Thanks for the help!

Comment: Their are a few options, `unique_ptr`, `shared_ptr` etc. But the simplest is to call the clean up or close function in the destructor of a class whose instance is tied to the lifetime of the data being imported from the dll. You could combine this with a `shared_ptr` to achieve a "last one out turns off the lights" type approach as well.

Comment: Also, how come the global data from the dll is not synchronised with the executable? As far as I can see the deconstructor of the global object will be destructed after return() is called, as expected, however the thread within the global object has then already been terminated. Do you have any ideas why?

Comment: I'm not sure on all the details with threads running in dlls as the process starts exiting, IIRC, they are "aborted" by the OS as the process exits; so basically their execution is no longer honoured.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions @Niall, however the issue is still that I then have to rely on the client to do a proper clean-up. As far as I understand it should be possible for for the dll to clean up the resources (since it actually works for the executable). Is it possible to "improve" the synchronisation of the data?

Comment: I'm not sure how it could be improved, it would be part of the loader and OS. You move the RAII mechanism into the dll and "force" the client to use it by exporting a class with the required mechanisms built in for functional access and resource management. This would break the C API requirements you have, but it requires less of the client. The C API is limiting in this regard, it would require some client cooperation, however little that is.

Comment: @A.Fagrell. I've added further notes to this answer given your updates and attempts with `DllMain`.

Comment: thanks for your explanation. I appreciate your help. However I feel like there should be a solution or to do what I want to do without changing the spec/requirements. I will use an IPC mutex within the thread so it's critical that is cleaned up properly.

Comment: If the issue is a mutex and not just a thread, that changes the problem quiet a bit. It is easier then to extract the mutex to a global level and allow `DllMain` to (with `DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH` etc.) to manage it. The thread would be allowed access thereof as per normal.

Comment: @A.Fagrell Bear in mind as well, WIN32 IPC mutex mechanism include an "abandoned" state as well. Depending on the other logic, you can explore this option as well. I've added further notes to the answer.

Comment: Thanks, I went for a Windows Mutex, as you said the abandoned state is very attractive. I'm still intrigued why the thread is terminated in the DLL-case as well as why there is not really a direct solution to solve it (just workarounds). Thanks though

Answer (score 1):

> It seems that of some reason when the main returns and `exit()` is called, thread is automatically killed/terminated.

This is the expected behaviour of `exit` function. I.e. it terminates the entire process and all its threads.

> Within the library there will be a global instance of an object which will have a `std::thread` as a member.

It looks like this object is not created when it is compiled into a `.dll`. You probably need to export that object explicitly, so that it is not optimized away because nothing in the `.dll` refers to it, e.g.:

```
__declspec(dllexport) std::unique_ptr<CThread> cthread;
```

Comment: I can't currently test your solution, however I have some comments/questions:
I know that the exit behaviour will terminate the process and threads, however the thread is already terminated/killed before the deconstructor of CThread is called (I expected it to be terminated after the deconstructor, which is does when it's not a library).

Also, if I put a breakpoint before the return in the main function I can see that the thread is running (It's in the infiniteLoop()-function). Shouldn't this imply that the object is created?

Comment: Yes it's the dll-version that I'm testing. I expect the code above to run in an infinite-loop which is doesn't for the dll-version. Explicity exporting the object didn't help me unfortunately.